# How to edit/update articles on big sites using Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I want to create SEO Niche Websites using Jekyll. Each of my websites will have 300-400 articles (posts).

And I have a question, how in future I can edit/update my posts?

I don't want to use Github for hosting, I'm planning to use virtual hosting with SSH.

And If I edit one single post, then I should upload all my website files every time? It's hard and very don't convenient.

Sorry guys for my English.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution is to let CloudCannon build the site and write the build to a DIFFERENT github repo called '[mygithubreposname]_static'. A webhook in this Github repo fires after update and pulls the build to my VM.

A simpler solution is to use a CD/CI tool, use CloudCannon or Netlify for hosting or to let CloudCannon deploy directly to your server.